# Can't get animation to load with three.js

Tags: three.js

I am loading a GLTF animation of a bird into my 3js app. Little bit confused as to why it wont work. If i console log te object is has an array index of 0 where the animation is stored. I added rotation as well to test and that wont work either. Any help is much appreciated.

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

loader.load("/assets/bird.gltf", function(gltf){
    
    //Loading in and positioning model
    var object = gltf.scene;
    object.scale.set(10,10,10);
    object.position.set (0, 0, 0);
    object.rotation.y = 0.5;

    //Playing Animation
     mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(gltf.scene);
     console.log(gltf.animations)
     mixer.clipAction( gltf.animations[0]).play();

    scene.add(object);  

});
```

Comment: Are you updating the animation mixer in your animation loop?

Comment: tried adding this

Comment: ```function update () {
 mixer.update( deltaSeconds );
}

Comment: then calling it in the animation loop

Comment: but it didnt work sorry for posting like 4 comments btw

Comment: Please share your complete code. As a live example or as a GitHub repo.

Comment: Thanks for the help btw, you helped me the other day aswell with the skybox xD here is a link to the github repo :https://github.com/benmarr2/ThreeJS-FlockingSimulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indeed do not update the instance of `THREE.AnimationMixer` correctly. Please create an instance of `THREE.Clock` and then use it to compute the time delta value passed to the mixer. Check out the updated code:

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, controls, mixer, clock;
initialiseScene();
animate();

function initialiseScene() {

    //scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene( { antialias: true } );

    //FOV, Aspect ratio, Near clip, Far clip
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 20000 );

    //renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    clock = new THREE.Clock();

}

//CONTROLS
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
camera.position.set( - 50, 50, 0 );
controls.update();

//LIGHT
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040, 5 ); // soft white light
scene.add( light );

//OBJECT LOADER
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

loader.load( "./assets/bird.gltf", function ( gltf ) {

    //Loading in and positioning model
    var object = gltf.scene;
    object.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
    object.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
    object.rotation.y = 0.5;

    //Playing Animation
    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( gltf.scene );
    console.log( gltf.animations );
    mixer.clipAction( gltf.animations[ 0 ] ).play();

    scene.add( object );

} );

//SKYBOX
const materialArray = [];
const texture_ft = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'assets/rainbow_ft.png' );
const texture_bk = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'assets/rainbow_bk.png' );
const texture_up = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'assets/rainbow_up.png' );
const texture_dn = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'assets/rainbow_dn.png' );
const texture_rt = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'assets/rainbow_rt.png' );
const texture_lf = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'assets/rainbow_lf.png' );

materialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_ft } ) );
materialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_bk } ) );
materialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_up } ) );
materialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_dn } ) );
materialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_rt } ) );
materialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_lf } ) );

for ( let i = 0; i < 6; i ++ )
    materialArray[ i ].side = THREE.BackSide;

const skyboxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10000, 10000, 10000 );
const skybox = new THREE.Mesh( skyboxGeo, materialArray );
scene.add( skybox );

window.addEventListener( 'resize', () => {

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

} );

//ANIMATE
function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    if ( mixer ) mixer.update( clock.getDelta() );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );


}
```